# Assign a workflow to a content type

Tags: 7, workflows

I had defined a new workflow which has 3 states and I want to assign it to a content type. I had tried to make a workflow file type in manage field but when I try to edit it I can not choose my workflow type.

[image]

I only can select "-Select a value-" but my workflow type defined don´t appear.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I have to make a configuration in "transition" tab (in the same place where I have defined states for my workflow). After that I can choose it.